# Implementation inline assembly of compare and swap function for Sparc V8

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, sparc

My gcc cross compiler doesn't support [Built-in functions for atomic memory access](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html). How i can implement the following function, using inline assembly for Sparc V8 architecture:

```
long __sync_val_compare_and_swap (long *ptr, long oldval long newval)
{
....
}
```

Those builtin perform an atomic compare and swap. That is, if the current value of *ptr is oldval, then write newval into *ptr.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276946/gcc-inline-assembly-for-sparc-architecture/9280379#9280379

Comment: test_cas.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `atomic_cas_8'

Comment: Linking with Solaris libc required ... or else, take the sources from http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/common/atomic/sparc/atomic.s to get it.

Answer (score 2):

SPARC V8 doesn't have a CAS instruction, so you'll have to emulate it somehow. E.g. use the C-like pseudocode for CAS at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/index-142944.html and use a static pthread mutex to ensure the atomicity of the atomic {} region.

Comment: A mutex isn't sufficient; it won't give reentrancy, so you'll also need to incur two syscalls per CAS to block and unblock all signals. A better solution would be to fix your kernel the same way Linux was fixed for ARM to use kernel-assisted CAS with no overhead in the non-interrupted case: http://lwn.net/Articles/314561/ Note that this will not work for SMP, but if you're trying to use SMP with a machine that cannot provide atomic CAS, well, that's not a good idea...

Comment: @R..: Right, just goes to show that emulating atomic primitives gets expensive if you want to take care of all the cases.. :) FWIW, SPARC V8 has the ldstub and swap atomic instructions, which are sufficient to implement a simple spinlock or similar, but AFAICS not general enough to allow a simple implementation of CAS in terms of them.

Comment: Note that conformant implementations of certain pthread primitives (especially semaphores) seem to require atomic CAS. Otherwise you run into self-synchronized destruction issues that do not seem to be solvable without kernel mediation for every operation (i.e. having the kernel fully emulate CAS by doing it in a syscall with interrupts disabled). Atomic swap is not sufficient.

Comment: As an aside, I started to wonder how the SPARC V8 LEON (or are there other relevant SPARC V8 implementations around these days?) processors support SMP Linux without CAS, and the answer is that, well, the SMP capable LEON versions have "backported" the CAS instruction from SPARC V9.

Comment: AFAIK, there is/was never such a thing as "pure `sparcv8`"; 32bit 'classical' SPARC (sun4/4m/4d) is `sparcv7` and indeed only knows `ldstub`/`swap`, but the 32bit mode of all 64bit-capable SPARCs (sun4u/us/v) is actually `sparcv8+` and _does_ have `cas` & friends. What (if any) actually _is_ the difference between sparcv8 and `sparcv8+`, and (assuming there _is_ any difference), what CPUs are `sparcv8` but not `sparcv8+` ?

Comment: @FrankH You are mistaken. Sun4c and older are Sparc v7, Sun4m an Sun4d were Sparc v8. Not that there are quite alot of sun4m machines in existance even alot of clones. The SparcStatoin 20  is the prime example of sun4m. And the SparcCenter 2000 was the largest sun4d. There is also the Cray 64000 a Sparcv8 Supercomputer that had up to 64 90Mhz SuperSparc processors on special modules (half size).

Comment: @cb88 we're both half-way-correct ... you're right that sun4m/sun4d are `sparcv8`, but I'm right that you require `sparcv8+` (the 32-bit mode of the UltraSparc CPUs / the "32bit `sparcv9` mode") for support of the `cas` instruction.

Comment: @FrankH I didn't mention CAS I was just pointing out that sun4m and d have nothing to do with v7. But now that you mention it and since its pertinent... Leon Sparc v8 actually does implement CASA which is from the v9 spec but just *makes sense* to have on a modern Sparc v8. You are right of courses about ldsub/swap on older machines though. I am running into this issue with updating Gentoo/Sparc systemd requires CAS (and noone wants/knows enough to fix it) now I might just fall back to mdev or eudev... sigh.