# Clang + AVR Compilation error: '=w' in asm

Tags: arduino, clang, llvm, avr

I got this error below and I can not find a solution. Does anybody know how
to fix this error?

```
rafael@ubuntu:~/avr/projeto$ clang -fsyntax-only -Os -I /usr/lib/avr/include -D__AVR_ATmega328P__ -DARDUINO=100 -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-attributes serial_tree.c
In file included from serial_tree.c:3:
In file included from /usr/lib/avr/include/util/delay.h:43:
/usr/lib/avr/include/util/delay_basic.h:108:5: error: invalid output
constraint
      '=w' in asm
                : "=w" (__count)
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9277012/1790864) is somewhat related.

Comment: What part of your command compiles it for the AVR?

Comment: The mainline version of clang (or rather, its backend LLVM) doesn't support compiling for AVR microcontrollers like that used on the Arduino. Have you tried using ``avr-gcc`` instead? A build of that ships as part of the Arduino IDE.

Comment: he's using '-fsyntax-only', so this is clearly for some autocompletion tool.

Comment: Looks like it's related to clangs internal assembler, does [How to switch off LLVM's integrated assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118887/how-to-switch-off-llvms-integrated-assembler) help?

Comment: AFAIK, clang doesn't have a back-end for AVR. You need a gcc cross-compiler (and binutils) for [AVR libc](http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[util/delay.h](http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) is a Header from avr-libc, and the feature which you are using (some of the delay stuff) is using inline asm to implement it.  avr-libc is written to be used with avr-gcc and uses features from avr-gcc like [machine dependent constrains](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#avr) in inline asm. llvm does not recognize constraint "w", thus you have to use a different approach like using avr-gcc or porting that code to llvm.

avr-gcc also implements built-in function [__builtin_avr_delay_cycles](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/AVR-Built-in-Functions.html) to implement wasting a specified number of clock cycles.  If llvm is properly mimicking avr-gcc, then you can use that function as a starting point.